# .toggle() function w/ classList not working for one element but works for others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, toggle

I am trying to add a class on an html element when I click on
another element of the page, but despite all my attempts it keeps not working.

Here is my code

**html code**:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contenu">
    <h2>Titre du contenu</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="popupBtn">
  </div>
</div>
```

**javascript code**:

```js
let popupBtn = document.querySelector('.popupBtn');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

popupBtn.onclick = function() {
    container.classList.toggle('active');
    //console.log(container.classList.toggle('active'));
};
```

So I think the javascript function is supposed to add (or remove) the class 'active' to the element that owns the class 'container' already, but the commented console.log() returns false on every click when I uncomment it when it should return alternatively `true` and `false` when I click several times on the element.

However when I replace

```js
container.classList.toggle('active');
```

by

```js
popupBtn.classList.toggle('active');
```

it works perfectly fine and adds a class 'active' to the element with the 'popupBtn' class.

Has anybody already met such a problem? I don't find anything of this kind on internet.
Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: It is working fine without replacing `container.classList.toggle('active');`

Comment: In the `console.log()` line use `contains()` not `toggle()` - you're just resetting the class again which is why it's always false.

Comment: @Shrey yes this works on the computer on my friend but not on mine and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you wanted to do?

Just set `.contains` instead of `.toggle` in your `console.log`.

I've just added a random css class, to see what is going on.

```js
let popupBtn = document.querySelector('.popupBtn');
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

popupBtn.onclick = function() {
    container.classList.toggle('active');
    console.log(container.classList.contains('active'));
};
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="contenu">
    <h2>Titre du contenu</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="popupBtn">text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I have this alternate `true` and `false` when I click several time on the element!
So I tried to replace .toggle by .contains in the line above but it doesn't do anything still

Comment: `Now I have this alternate true and false when I click several time on the element!` Yes - that's what it supposed to do, and what your question asks for...? I'm confused what your comment is saying the problem is?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Same. I'm kind of confused right now.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I didn't understand your answer, I thought you wanted me to try with .contains to see something that might help. In fact when I changed for .contains instead of .toggle the console.log return the alternate true/false but the class 'active' still doesn't appear in the html code

Comment: Well it can't just add the HTML code, inside your file. If you check your code via Inspect option (right click on the page -> Inspect -> Elements), and you find your desired element, you can see that HTML code actually comes and goes. Here are the pictures so you can see the difference. https://prnt.sc/kVxuIR1jmLtE without the class, and https://prnt.sc/mr2k7Gq3E8AR with the class. That's what `toggle` does, and `contains` will just return true or false.

Comment: Yes of course it doesn't add a class in the code editor ^^, I am already using the code inspector to see if a click does a modification or not, but when I click it doesn't add/remove anything. That's why I'm so confused about this pb, there is no reason why this code isn't working

Comment: @Yann I think that `console.log` confuses you. You need to understand that, code that you write inside of `console.log()` actually gets both executed, and written in the console. So basically, if you `console.log(container.classList.toggle('active'));` as you did, you will always remove the class, and it will always be false.  Here is an example, showing that code actually do what you tell him to do, inside of console.log. https://jsfiddle.net/2Lq1az6m/2/

Comment: Yes I know that, I always comment one of the two line to avoid that. But even when I get the alternate true/false in the console, the active class doesn't appear, even with the exact same code you showed me in the link (thank you for that btw)